# Rails自体をテストする方法はどこに記述されていますか？

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails自体のタグヘルパーに手を入れたいと思っています。
そこで、既存のソースのテストをまず試みようと思ったのですが、うまくいきません。

[rails/rails at 4-2-stable: Ruby on Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/4-2-stable)
コミット番号：e531c86e6bb0b623cd18c97a7a32ba981e8fb2ce

で

`% rake test actionview/test/template/form_tag_helper_test.rb`
してみましたが、下記のようになってしまいます（しかも全部貼るには長すぎるので冒頭部分のみ）

```
/Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby -w -I"lib:test" -I"/Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0" "/Users/shingo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/**/*_test.rb" 
W, [2016-02-20T23:29:17.850357 #40889]  WARN -- : localhost:11211 failed (count: 0) Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 11211
Skipping memcached tests. Start memcached and try again.
Run options: --seed 60706
```

以上のようになったので今度は、

```
% brew install memcached
% memcached
```

したのですが、次から次にテストが失敗したり、Errorが発生したりとしらみつぶしではキリがありません。どこかにテストに必要な前準備等は記載されていないのでしょうか？

Comment: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#running-tests

Comment: @h2so5 ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

コメントに頂いた通り
[Contributing to Ruby on Rails — Ruby on Rails Guides](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#running-tests)
や
[Ruby on Rails に貢献する方法 | Rails ガイド](http://railsguides.jp/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#rails%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B3%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%81%AB%E8%B2%A2%E7%8C%AE%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)
に記載がありました。